# Offline identification of Windows version in a Linux environment

Tags: windows, ntfs, clonezilla

I am trying to customize a [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) Live iso to be able to conveniently take snapshots of different Windows installations (XP, Vista, Win7, Win8). Ideally I would like to boot the machine on a CD that automatically identifies the Windows version and creates a snapshot with a name containing the OS (something like `Windows_XP_2013-06-17`).

Is there a way to programatically **identify what version of Windows** is installed on an NTFS partition mounted in a Linux live environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **strings** command to access registry files, I tested in my machine and it worked:

```
strings /media/cuonglm/Windows/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE | grep -e '^6.1.*' | head -n 1
```

Ouput:

```
6.1.7601.17608
```

It denotes my version is Windows 7 SP1.

I think it is the faster way than using some tools to manipulate properties of PE files, or registry files.

Comment: How would this command work if the version number doesn't start with 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can access Windows registry using tools like `chntpw`. You need the following keys, located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`:

```
ProductName
Version
VersionNumber
SubVersionNumber
```

You can create a script that will automate `chntpw` and parse registry keys to identify Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

There are several non-windows and non-command solutions which you can use with your problem. Here are few ideas what I though:

**Boot.ini**

Try reading boot.ini from Windows boot-partion (i.e. C:\boot.ini) text-file. This (usually) has a default boot information if it has not been manually changed. You can read the text file and do RegEx to find out version.

For example, my boot.ini has "Microsoft Windows XP Professional" part which can be easily parsed with any Regular Expression.

**Check file system structure**

You may get some clue about the general version of the Windows by looking for directory structure it uses: Windows XP - family uses C:\Documents and Settings kind of directory 
structure (language dependent) as other later versions use different kind of directories.

This one is not a good solution, but it is one solution.

**cmd.exe**

For this one I'm not completely sure, but I think I remember that Windows' command prompt binary file (cmd.exe) has a version stored into it. By reading binary file and it's resources, could help determing correct version.

Still, of all these solutions, I would suggest you to try reading boot.ini. It is user customizable but very rarely changed by a regular users.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to ntoskrl.exe version info gives both numeric and textual results

```
me@host:/mnt$ iconv -cf utf16 Windows/System32/ntoskrnl.exe|strings|grep  6\\.
6.1.7601.18409 (win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
6.1.7601.18409
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linux, here Ubuntu, you can use `chntpw`.

I did this:

```
sudo apt install chntpw
chntpw -e /path/to/windisk/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE
cat \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

and was told that the version was `Windows 10 Home`. Note that the capitalization in the path may differ across versions, so look if it doesn't work. One plae also mentioned  a `RegBack` folder occurring int he path (sorry, I forgot where).

Additional details may be found through other keys. To list other keys in `CurrentVersion`,  while in `chntpw`, do

```
ls \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Answer (score -1):

Get Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder.  The portable free version works fine.

Start it up, and under the tools menu select >> load hive.  It then shows all your drives, select the windows folder of the drive in question.

Comment: Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder is a Windows program which would almost certainly not run under a Clonezilla/Linux Live environment as describer by OP.

Comment: I agree keyfinder runs within windows, but he has access to the various windows NTFS partitions.  You just need to see them from a windows box to run  keyfinder, which will identify each partition.

Answer (score -1):

How to find out the version of Windows if the system is offline?
Here's an answer for professionals using Sleuthkit Autopsies

- Windows/system 32/config/SOFTWARE
- then on "application"
- Microsoft/Windows NT/Current Version
- everything is written there.

The other way is, extract and properties of the ntdll.dll file located in Windows/system32/.